# How to share an sd card across different pi models

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, pi-1

I have installed Noobs 2.4.2 with Raspbian 8 on Pi 3. Kernel 4.9.35-v7+. It works, but now I need to run the system that's on the sd card on another board which is Pi 1 Model B. It doesn't boot, says kernel panic not syncing attempted to kill init exit code 0000000x4.

I've read that it's because Pi3 board has some features that are used on boot that earlier models don't have. How can I disable those, so that it worked?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure one of the numerous barriers you may be facing is that the Pi 3 uses arms v8 architecture and the Pi model 1 uses arms v6 architecture. Which kind of makes what you're trying to do impossible without integrating multiple kernels into one os and having the system choose which kernel to use on boot.

Comment: Actually , Raspbian has been designed with this in mind. It is the only OS which ships with multiple kernels and targets the lowest common denominator in its packages : ARMv6. Something else must've went wrong.

Comment: I think retropie must include multiple kernels too, as I am able to use the same SD card between a P1B (ARM11, v6) and a Pi3(Cortex A53, ARM v8-A)